# Getting "value", "color", "label" from existing palette raster layer in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, categorized-renderer, pyqgis-3, rendering

```
    renderer = activaterlayer.renderer()
    symboloyitems = renderer.legendSymbologyItems()
    label = symboloyitems[i][0]
    color = symboloyitems[i][1].getRgb()
    value = ?
```

How can I get the corresponding "value" attribution?

Using legendSymbologyItems I can not get the corresponding "value".  other function of "renderer"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
renderer = activaterlayer.renderer()
classes = renderer.classes()
label = classes[i].label
color = classes[i].color
value = classes[i].value
```